# onPaste scroll move to top on quilljs

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I am using ngx-quill : 19.0.1 and when there are more than 4 paragraphs inside the editor the paste events causes the scroll to jump to the top and stay there. I came accross [ngx-quill-paste](https://github.com/virendrasinghpawar/ngx-quill-paste) developed by a dude who faced this issue before. This works for me but the ctrl+v image paste functionality is not present in this dependency.

I am thinking about creating a custom module for quill using the register() function which will override the default onPaste() method so that the need for an additional dependency can be eliminated by implementing it internally. `Quill.register('modules/paste', customPasteHandler);`Can someone point me in the right direction to implement something like that. Any references or guides or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any poor soul who finds himself on the same treacherous situation save your time. This [Angular Solution](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1374#issuecomment-538730413) for ngx-quill, quilljs will be what you need. Alternative solution is to utilize this [css solution](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1374#issuecomment-520296215). The only issue with the css solution is that when new content is copied and pasted, the position of the cursor wont be at the end of the new content , it will be in the same place where cursor was when ctr+v was performed